# Woocommerce sale shortcode not showing all updated products from dokan wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, dokan

We have dokan + woocommerce running platform. Currently when user update sale price from vendor dashboard dokan, its not showing in sale page. Apparently, it shows only product that updates from woocommerce directly. So i created custom sale shortcode but still it works like that not showing all sale products.

Below, I attach the custom Shortcode. Meanwhile may I know is there any way can make WooCommerce update the products from third party plugin?

```
if( ! function_exists('get_preordable_products') ) {

    function get_preordable_products( $atts ) {
        // Shortcode Attributes
        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'columns'    => '4',
            'limit'      => '20',
        ), $atts, 'preordable_products' ) );

        // The WP_Query
        $query = new WP_Query( array (
            'post_type'         => 'product',
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'    => $limit,
        ) );

        global $woocommerce_loop;

        $woocommerce_loop['columns']      = $columns;
        $woocommerce_loop['is_shortcode'] = 1;
        $woocommerce_loop['total']        = $query->post_count;
        $woocommerce_loop['total_pages']  = $query->max_num_pages;
        $woocommerce_loop['per_page']     = $limit;

        ob_start();

        if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            woocommerce_product_loop_start();

            while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
               $query->the_post();
                  $id = get_the_ID();
            $_product = wc_get_product();
            if($_product->is_on_sale()){  
             wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
            }
            }
            woocommerce_product_loop_end();
            woocommerce_reset_loop();
            wp_reset_postdata();
        } else {
            do_action( "woocommerce_shortcode_products_loop_no_results", $atts );

            echo '<p>'. __("Aucun article disponible à la précommande.") . '</p>';
        }

        $content = ob_get_clean();

        return '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $columns . '">' . $content . '</div>';
    }

    add_shortcode( 'preordable_products', 'get_preordable_products' );
}
```